# mysql won't return the correct results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am trying to implement a search on my simple forum using this SQL:

```
SELECT t.topic_id, t.`topic_title` , t.author_id, t.`creation_date` , u.username
FROM  `forum_topics` t
LEFT JOIN  `users` u ON t.author_id = u.user_id
AND MATCH (
t.`topic_title`
)
AGAINST (
? IN BOOLEAN MODE
)
ORDER BY t.creation_date DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

So it just matches words against the title, the problem I am having is it is returning the same results everytime no matter the words. Testing it in phpmyadmin gives me no usernames meaning the join isn't working and I've no idea why as the author_id matches the user_id fine.

What am i missing that's so obvious I cannot see it?

Comment: Can you give an idea of search terms that are failing?

Comment: Well for example I search for "test" and get lots of forum topic titles that don't contain the word "test".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the problem is obvious.  You are using a `left join` which keeps everything even with no match.  Move the condition to a `where` clause:

```
SELECT t.topic_id, t.`topic_title` , t.author_id, t.`creation_date` , u.username
FROM  `forum_topics` t LEFT JOIN 
      `users` u
       ON t.author_id = u.user_id
WHERE MATCH (t.`topic_title`) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY t.creation_date DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```